# Application_Start Event in Global.asax not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a task to run every minute and decided to put it in the `Application_Start` event in `Global.asax` file to execute as soon as the application is started. When I run it (without debugging and in debug mode), It doesn't fire up.

I tried to put it in `Session_Start` event just to make sure it's not from the markup of the `Global.asax` file and it worked perfectly. But unfortunately, It has to be when the Application starts and not when a session starts.

This is my Global.asax (ASP.NET 2.0, VS2008) below:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="TaskManager" %>

<script runat="server">

    private TaskScheduler _scheduler = null;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(Server.MapPath(@"\Config\tasks.config"));
        XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("Tasks/Task");

        this._scheduler = new TaskScheduler(nodes);
        this._scheduler.StartTasks();
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        this._scheduler.StopTasks();
    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Try after recycling the app pool / IIS (wherever you have hosted your application)

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Thanks for your response. It's hosted on ASP.NET Development server. How do I recycle that?

Comment: So, basically Application_Start event runs only once when the application first time runs. It run again whenever the application restarts (example: change in webconfig, application pool recycle or IIS restarted etc). If you want to quickly verify, just try to make a minor edit in your web.config and run the application again. This time, the breakpoint should hit the Application_Start method.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I edited the web.config, cleaned and rebuilt the solution but no joy. The breakpoint didn't get hit.

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641148/application-start-not-firing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693020/application-start-not-being-hit-in-asp-net-web-app

Comment: It's very challenging to step into Global.asax via Visual Studio.  The easiest way I've found is to host the site in IIS Express for debugging/development purposes (though I strongly prefer Local IIS and only use express when I need to see what's happening in Global.asax).

Comment: I restarted IIS but no joy. **sad face**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I cant comment due to rep - but if having trouble you could resort to System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); in combination with any of the above (editing web.cofig etc)